# I can't use php with mongodb sixtaxe error?

Tags: php, mongodb, nosql

Hello I have a problem connecting to mongodb and selecting a database and even consulting something, I installed all the add-ons for the mongo driver for php on ubuntu, however I don't know what I'm missing, I'm trying to use codes ready to just log in to the bank and print what's there but it doesn't work

```
    <?php

$manager = new \MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://user:pwd@ip:port");
print '<pre>';
var_dump($manager);
print '</pre>';

$db = $manager->selectDB('db');
$collection = new MongoCollection($db, 'customers');

$sweetQuery = array('Details.db' => 'sim');
echo "sim\n";
```

In ubuntu in the apache logo it returns the following error: Call to a member function selectDB() on null in
and the location of the file and the line where it is wrong
in this case, line 6 .

detail I changed the port of the mongo but put in a normal management tool the database with user and password that I passed but I don't know if I'm doing it right in php, I never used the mongo if you can give me the direction of where I'm going wrong appreciate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to import this lib https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-library
and change your connection:

```
$manager = new MongoDB\Client("mongodb://user:pwd@ip:port");
$db = $manager->db;
```

I hope it helped you.